# Finding the install path to a detected package

Tags: c#, wix, burn

When Burn detects that one of it's packages is installed,
how can you find the install path of the detected package?

None of the events on IBootstrapperApplication seem to expose it, and Google hasn't turned up anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment—I'll edit this with answer content later...

Burn doesn't know (nor does it need to know) anything about a package installation other than what's in the `*Package` element.

**What do you mean by the "install path of the package"?**  Windows Installer can report the `InstallLocation` of an `MsiPackage` *if it is set*—see [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/1/14/arpinstalllocation-and-how-to-set-it-with-the-wix-toolset).

For an `ExePackage`, detection is just a bundle-defined yes/no check.

For an `MsiPackage`, Windows Installer gives the yes/no answer but does have an API for other information that Burn doesn't need. **Does your question relate to an `MsiPackage`?**

**What problem are you trying to solve?**

UPDATE:

A Windows Installer package doesn't actually have a installed location; Components have installed locations. It is a very common practice to organize the locations for all or most components into a common directory tree and to allow the root directory to be selected. Components can be grouped into different features and some installers allow selecting a different root directory for each feature, but the mechanism is the same. These root directories don't mean anything to Windows Installer once the directory for each component is computed.

If the directories are desired for maintenance, they must be saved—commonly to a vendor/application-specific location in the registry. A WiX Product can [write](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/write_a_registry_entry.htm) this information and read it using a [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm). A Wix Bundle can read it using a [util:RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_registrysearch.htm). If that doesn't get the specific information desired, a WiX Product can use a custom action and a WiX Bundle can use a custom BootstrapperApplication. Both can use the Windows Installer API via [C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), COM or .NET (using WiX's DTF library).

So, hopefully, you are currently authoring version "1" of the package and can make it record the location(s) you need using the built-in registry facilities.

Comment: Yes, it is the path of an installed MsiPackage I am trying to find.
I am showing a custom feature select tree for the MSI in question when modifying the install, and would like to show the path like the MSI itself does (and allow it to be changed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, helps a lot. Will go the registry route then I guess. :-)